# Oracle SQL Developer - looking for "create table" code in history

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

With some org changes, I am now the department's SQL person and am learning best I can. I created a table last month with certain fields and a sequential column (learned from this site). However, the company wants me to create the exact same table in another environment for QA. I am trying to find my code but it doesn't show up in View > SQL History for the dates I created it. It looks like all my SELECT statements. Where can I find the code I used to create the table so I can duplicate that effort in the QA environment so I don't have to research it again. I promise to save it this time. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A simple option is to **export** both DDL (data description language; that's the `create table` statement, along with possible constraints etc.) and data.

How? Right-click table name (1), choose "Export" from the menu (2), follow the wizard (set any option you find appropriate; if you aren't sure what to select, try various options and check the result). I chose to export DDL and data in INSERT format; result is stored into a file on my disk, and it looks as (3) on this screenshot.

If you need DDL only, un-check the "Export data" checkbox.

[image]

Alternatively (for DDL only), select table (1) and click the SQL tab on the right-hand side:

[image]